# How to deal with randomstate in AdaBoostRegressor?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In scikit-learn, `AdaBoostRegressor` uses `AdaBoost.R2` algorithm. The first step of this algorithm is to bootstrap samples according to the updated weight. Bootstrap means it selects sample from the training set with replacement. In this way, it can achieve the goal of focusing more on those samples which are classified wrongly, since those examples will have larger weights and are more likely to be chosen in the bootstrap process.

However, there are two problems with it.

First, this randomness will make the results very different. Like, if I set the parameter `n_estimator = 1` and use `DecisionTreeRegressor` as base learner, it will give a different result from directly using a `DecisionTreeRegressor`, which are supposed to be the same. And setting different `random_state` will also gives different result. This means it is not robust. I wonder if there is any solution to reduce the unrobustness. I know the algorithm itself is right.

Second, actually, `DecisionTreeRegressor` has the parameter `sample_weight`, which means it can directly learn a hypothesis according to the sample weight, without the need of bootstrap. I know as a framework, `AdaBoostRegressor` can involve more base learner which does not have the `sample_weight` using this bootstrapping sampling. However, this brings a new question. Why doesn't `AdaBoostClassifier` use this bootstrapping sampling method?

Reference to `_boost` function in `weight_boosting.py` from sklearn.